# Java Nashorn Generic Classes Declaration

Tags: javascript, java, generics, nashorn

Can anyone help me declare a class like this in Java Nashorn HttpEntity. Here is a sample script I am trying to run.

--This my declaration somewhere in the code--

```
var JavascriptValidator = Java.type('ph.com.bdo.tbg.icos.validation.form.JavascriptValidator');
var HttpHeaders = Java.type('org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders');
var DateTimeFormatter = Java.type('java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter');
var Arrays = Java.type('java.util.Arrays');
var Date = Java.type('java.util.Date');
var MediaType = Java.type('org.springframework.http.MediaType');
var HttpEntity = Java.type('org.springframework.http.HttpEntity');
var UriComponentsBuilder = Java.type('org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder');
var RestTemplate = Java.type('org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate');
```

--This is a sample function I am running--

```
    function init(){
            var headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            headers.add("username", username);
            headers.add("password", password);

            var entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

            // more code... 
        }
```

--Then I get the following error--

```
FAILED: testFinalValidate
<eval>:73 TypeError: Can not create new object with constructor org.springframework.http.HttpEntity with the passed arguments; they do not match any of its method signatures.
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.error(ECMAErrors.java:57)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.typeError(ECMAErrors.java:213)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.typeError(ECMAErrors.java:185)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.typeError(ECMAErrors.java:172)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.NashornStaticClassLinker.checkNullConstructor(NashornStaticClassLinker.java:108)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.NashornStaticClassLinker.getGuardedInvocation(NashornStaticClassLinker.java:96)
at jdk.internal.dynalink.support.CompositeTypeBasedGuardingDynamicLinker.getGuardedInvocation(CompositeTypeBasedGuardingDynamicLinker.java:176)
at jdk.internal.dynalink.support.CompositeGuardingDynamicLinker.getGuardedInvocation(CompositeGuardingDynamicLinker.java:124)
at jdk.internal.dynalink.support.LinkerServicesImpl.getGuardedInvocation(LinkerServicesImpl.java:154)
at jdk.internal.dynalink.DynamicLinker.relink(DynamicLinker.java:253)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$2$2171$\^eval\_.init(<eval>:73)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$1$1772A$\^eval\_.finalValidate(<eval>:59)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:639)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:494)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:393)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror.call(ScriptObjectMirror.java:117)
at com.bdo.icos.util.BaseTest.runScript(BaseTest.java:194)
at com.bdo.icos.validation.SmartMoneyTest.testFinalValidate(SmartMoneyTest.java:130)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
at org.testng.internal.InvokeMethodRunnable.runOne(InvokeMethodRunnable.java:54)
at org.testng.internal.InvokeMethodRunnable.run(InvokeMethodRunnable.java:44)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please note that the code if converted into equivalent Java syntax it would compile and run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Does the class org.springframework.http.HttpEntity have the correct *public* constructor accepting HttpHeaders ? Note that only public constructors and methods callable from script. protected /package-private/private members are not accessible.

Also this syntax->

```
var entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
```

won't work (appears to be cut-paste from java code)

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Yes the I am using the correct public constructor. As a work around I am using the following in my code instead "var entity = new HttpEntity(headers)" as it still works. However does that mean there is no equivalent syntax for String part of "new HttpEntity<String>()".